# Creating a custom calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to code a custom calculator that will take input parameters such as entry price, target price and stop loss values, and then calculate projected profits and losses. Once I've got it running nicely and optimized it a bit, I want to try and add functionality where I can place the data into an Excel or Google spreadsheet, however, I need to get the main part to work first. I'm using tkinter so that I can create a GUI.

I'm very new to coding and this is what I've managed to whip up so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Create labels for each parameter
label_Amount = Label(root, text="Amount:")
label_StopLoss = Label(root, text="Stop loss:")
label_EntryPrice = Label(root, text="Entry price:")
label_TargetPrice = Label(root, text="Target price:")
label_ProjectedLoss = Label(root, text="Projected loss:")
label_PLRatio = Label(root, text="P/L Ratio:")
label_ProjectedProfit = Label(root, text="Projected profit:")

#Create inputs
entry_Amount = Entry(root)
entry_StopLoss = Entry(root)
entry_EntryPrice = Entry(root)
entry_TargetPrice = Entry(root)

#Place labels
label_Amount.grid(row=0, column=2)
label_StopLoss.grid(row=1, column= 0)
label_ProjectedLoss.grid(row=2, column=0)
label_EntryPrice.grid(row=1, column=2)
label_PLRatio.grid(row=2, column=2)
label_TargetPrice.grid(row=1, column=4)
label_ProjectedProfit.grid(row=2, column=4)

#Place inputs
Amount_val = entry_Amount.grid(row=0, column=3)
StopLoss_val = entry_StopLoss.grid(row=1, column=1)
EntryPrice_val = entry_EntryPrice.grid(row=1, column=3)
TargetPrice_val = entry_TargetPrice.grid(row=1, column=5)

#Calculation long function
def calculateLong():
    projectedLoss_val = (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val) - (StopLoss_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedLoss_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedLoss_val))

    projectedProfit_val = (TargetPrice_val * Amount_val) - (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedProfit_val))

    PLRatio_val = projectedProfit_val / projectedLoss_val
    label_PLRatio_val = Label(root, text=str(PLRatio_val))

    label_ProjectedLoss_val.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val.grid(row=2, column=5)
    label_PLRatio_val.grid(row=2, column=3)

#Calcualtion short function
def calculateShort():
    projectedLoss_val = (StopLoss_val * Amount_val) - (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedLoss_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedLoss_val))

    projectedProfit_val = (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val) - (TargetPrice_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedProfit_val))

    PLRatio_val = projectedProfit_val / projectedLoss_val
    label_PLRatio_val = Label(root, text=str(PLRatio_val))

    label_ProjectedLoss_val.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val.grid(row=2, column=5)
    label_PLRatio_val.grid(row=2, column=3)

#Create long and short buttons that trigger functions
button_long = Button(root, text="Calculate long", bg="green", command=calculateLong)
button_short = Button(root, text="Calculate short", bg="red", command=calculateShort)

#Position the buttons to either side of Amount
button_long.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2)
button_short.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)




root.mainloop()
```

I think that my current error at the moment is with my inputs (either line 14 or 29, I'm not sure). The error I'm currently observing is stating that my inputs are **NoneType**, so I can't perform operations on the numbers I input. The exact error is:

```
projectedLoss_val = (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val) - (StopLoss_val * Amount_val)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

I think I just need to change the value to a float type or I'm doing something wrong with the creation and/or placements of the inputs.

Comment: You have to actually retrieve the input using `.get` function which will give You the inputed value

Answer (score 0):

You are using the grid variable to get data instead of using the input variable. also you need to use `get()` to get data. You get the data in string format and so need to convert it to int or float.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Create labels for each parameter
label_Amount = Label(root, text="Amount:")
label_StopLoss = Label(root, text="Stop loss:")
label_EntryPrice = Label(root, text="Entry price:")
label_TargetPrice = Label(root, text="Target price:")
label_ProjectedLoss = Label(root, text="Projected loss:")
label_PLRatio = Label(root, text="P/L Ratio:")
label_ProjectedProfit = Label(root, text="Projected profit:")

#Create inputs
entry_Amount = Entry(root)
entry_StopLoss = Entry(root)
entry_EntryPrice = Entry(root)
entry_TargetPrice = Entry(root)

#Place labels
label_Amount.grid(row=0, column=2)
label_StopLoss.grid(row=1, column= 0)
label_ProjectedLoss.grid(row=2, column=0)
label_EntryPrice.grid(row=1, column=2)
label_PLRatio.grid(row=2, column=2)
label_TargetPrice.grid(row=1, column=4)
label_ProjectedProfit.grid(row=2, column=4)

#Place inputs
Amount_val = entry_Amount.grid(row=0, column=3)
StopLoss_val = entry_StopLoss.grid(row=1, column=1)
EntryPrice_val = entry_EntryPrice.grid(row=1, column=3)
TargetPrice_val = entry_TargetPrice.grid(row=1, column=5)

#Calculation long function
def calculateLong():
    projectedLoss_val = (int(entry_EntryPrice.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get())) - (int(entry_StopLoss.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get()))
    label_ProjectedLoss_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedLoss_val))

    projectedProfit_val = (int(entry_TargetPrice.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get())) - (int(entry_EntryPrice.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get()))
    label_ProjectedProfit_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedProfit_val))

    PLRatio_val = projectedProfit_val / projectedLoss_val
    label_PLRatio_val = Label(root, text=str(PLRatio_val))

    label_ProjectedLoss_val.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val.grid(row=2, column=5)
    label_PLRatio_val.grid(row=2, column=3)

#Calcualtion short function
def calculateShort():
    projectedLoss_val = (int(entry_StopLoss.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get())) - (int(entry_EntryPrice.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get()))
    label_ProjectedLoss_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedLoss_val))

    projectedProfit_val = (int(entry_EntryPrice.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get())) - (int(entry_TargetPrice.get()) * int(entry_Amount.get()))
    label_ProjectedProfit_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedProfit_val))

    PLRatio_val = projectedProfit_val / projectedLoss_val
    label_PLRatio_val = Label(root, text=str(PLRatio_val))

    label_ProjectedLoss_val.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val.grid(row=2, column=5)
    label_PLRatio_val.grid(row=2, column=3)

#Create long and short buttons that trigger functions
button_long = Button(root, text="Calculate long", bg="green", command=calculateLong)
button_short = Button(root, text="Calculate short", bg="red", command=calculateShort)

#Position the buttons to either side of Amount
button_long.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2)
button_short.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

so here is the code that works (tho there is an issue with division by zero):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Create labels for each parameter
label_Amount = Label(root, text="Amount:")
label_StopLoss = Label(root, text="Stop loss:")
label_EntryPrice = Label(root, text="Entry price:")
label_TargetPrice = Label(root, text="Target price:")
label_ProjectedLoss = Label(root, text="Projected loss:")
label_PLRatio = Label(root, text="P/L Ratio:")
label_ProjectedProfit = Label(root, text="Projected profit:")

#Create inputs
entry_Amount = Entry(root)
entry_StopLoss = Entry(root)
entry_EntryPrice = Entry(root)
entry_TargetPrice = Entry(root)

#Place labels
label_Amount.grid(row=0, column=2)
label_StopLoss.grid(row=1, column= 0)
label_ProjectedLoss.grid(row=2, column=0)
label_EntryPrice.grid(row=1, column=2)
label_PLRatio.grid(row=2, column=2)
label_TargetPrice.grid(row=1, column=4)
label_ProjectedProfit.grid(row=2, column=4)

#Place inputs
entry_Amount.grid(row=0, column=3)
entry_StopLoss.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry_EntryPrice.grid(row=1, column=3)
entry_TargetPrice.grid(row=1, column=5)

#Calculation long function
def calculateLong():
    global entry_Amount, entry_StopLoss, entry_EntryPrice, entry_TargetPrice
    Amount_val = int(entry_Amount.get())
    EntryPrice_val = int(entry_EntryPrice.get())
    StopLoss_val = int(entry_StopLoss.get())
    TargetPrice_val = int(entry_TargetPrice.get())

    projectedLoss_val = (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val) - (StopLoss_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedLoss_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedLoss_val))

    projectedProfit_val = (TargetPrice_val * Amount_val) - (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedProfit_val))

    PLRatio_val = projectedProfit_val / projectedLoss_val
    label_PLRatio_val = Label(root, text=str(PLRatio_val))

    label_ProjectedLoss_val.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val.grid(row=2, column=5)
    label_PLRatio_val.grid(row=2, column=3)

#Calcualtion short function
def calculateShort():
    StopLoss_val = int(entry_StopLoss.get())
    Amount_val = int(entry_Amount.get())
    EntryPrice_val = int(entry_EntryPrice.get())
    TargetPrice_val = int(entry_TargetPrice.get())

    projectedLoss_val = (StopLoss_val * Amount_val) - (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedLoss_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedLoss_val))

    projectedProfit_val = (EntryPrice_val * Amount_val) - (TargetPrice_val * Amount_val)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val = Label(root, text=str(projectedProfit_val))

    PLRatio_val = projectedProfit_val / projectedLoss_val
    label_PLRatio_val = Label(root, text=str(PLRatio_val))

    label_ProjectedLoss_val.grid(row=2, column=1)
    label_ProjectedProfit_val.grid(row=2, column=5)
    label_PLRatio_val.grid(row=2, column=3)

#Create long and short buttons that trigger functions
button_long = Button(root, text="Calculate long", bg="green", command=calculateLong)
button_short = Button(root, text="Calculate short", bg="red", command=calculateShort)

#Position the buttons to either side of Amount
button_long.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2)
button_short.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)




root.mainloop()
```

remember that there has to be a way to retreive the information each time You call the function

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure I'm thinking about this right, you've used `global` to ensure that the variable values are changed throughout the entire script and not just within their respective functions? Does listing all the variables after `global` just tell Python to make ALL of those variables global? And then you've just used the `get()` command to retrieve the information from the inputs, converted them to integers, performed operations, then output a string of the answer. I'm assuming I can replace `int` with `float` with no issues.

Comment: Also, I'll never be inputting 0, so I don't think division by 0 is a problem, but thank you for highlighting it none the less.

Comment: @Mo0rBy I don't know much about gloabl it actually seems that it is not needed in this case (for some reason)  it's just that sometimes they are out of scope (but in this case it seems not needed) and there should not be any problems if You replaced `int` with `float`, except even if You inputed whole number the output will have a `.0` at the end. (tho that is somehow fixable)